# Remove upgrade button in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, php, html, tinymce, wamp

I am using tinymce in inline mode and am new to the tool.
I've gotten my text field input to look how I want with minimal editing buttons.
However, I am stumped on how to remove the "Upgrade" button from the toolbar when the text field is active.

[image]

Is this even possible?

Here is the initialization that I am using.
I am using a self-hosted community installation on a WAMP server.

`

```
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#addressinput',
        inline: true,
        toolbar: 'bold underline italic superscript',
        menubar: '',
        branding: false,
        force_br_newlines : true,
        min_height: 100
    });
</script>
```

`

Comment: Find out this button's selector (class there i guess) and hide it with CSS `display: none`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The TinyMCE Docs include instructions for turning the [Premium Upgrade Promotion Option](https://tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/editor-premium-upgrade-promotion/#premium-upgrade-promotion-option) off.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. I must have missed it in the docs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 45):

The above link^ to the Docs explains the step involved. Essentially, the following will disable the upgrade item:

```
tinymce.init({
//other configuration,
promotion: false
});
```